# Cursor is not initialized correctly SQLite Database Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, exception

I'm trying to get all the data from the SQLite database in android using this code below. When running it, it crashes and gives me this exception ->

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + menuItemTable,null);

    if(c.moveToFirst() && c != null){
        do{
            Log.d("Log->", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TitleField)));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
```

Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

The rest of the stacktrace

```
07-31 13:12:49.919 19572-19572/tnstudio.android.ubb_application E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
07-31 13:12:49.920 19572-19572/tnstudio.android.ubb_application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tnstudio.android.ubb_application, PID: 19572
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tnstudio.android.ubb_application/tnstudio.android.ubb_application.UBBNewsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at tnstudio.android.ubb_application.DatabaseHelper.getFeedItems(DatabaseHelper.java:95)
        at tnstudio.android.ubb_application.UBBNewsActivity.onCreate(UBBNewsActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: Have you formatted your question correctly? You're missing your opening quote-mark `"` from your `SELECT` statement

Comment: And what row count do you get when you dump `c.getCount()` to Logcat?

Comment: Are u sure  Your Table is Created Or Hear in SQLlite  Database

Comment: I get a count of 11, so all my data is correctly inserted.

Comment: Can you post the surrounding lines of your stacktrace? Specifically, do you see the message `Window is full`?

Comment: @MichaelDodd added the rest of the stacktrace

Comment: I note that this is happening in `onCreate()`. What if you moved your database actions to a later point of the activity lifecycle e.g. to `onResume()`?

Comment: Are you sure that the code you have shown is from the `getFeedItems` method in the `DatabaseHelper` class? as that is where the error is being issued from according to the log. The error is due to you attempting to read the first row when there are no rows in the Cursor. P.S. checking Cursor for null, when it is returned from rawQuery or query methods does nothing as it will not be null. A Cursor may be empty, in which case the Cursor's `getCount` method would return 0.